# Spring batch - Minio java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-s3, minio, socketexception

I have a spring boot application with different batch config class, one of my batch config reads a file from minio and split it to 3 files created on minio also.
The config class contains a job called loadFactureItemsJob

```
@Bean("loadFactureItemsJob")
    public Job loadFactureItemsJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,@Qualifier("loadFactureEnteteStep") Step loadFactureEnteteStep,
            @Qualifier("loadFactureLigneStep") Step loadFactureLigneStep, @Qualifier("loadFacturePaiementStep") Step loadFacturePaiementStep,
            @Qualifier("separateCsvStep") Step separateCsvStep,StepBuilderFactory stepBuilder,@Qualifier("errorFactureItemStep") Step stepError
            ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("loadFactureItemsJob")
                .start(separateCsvStep)
                .next(loadFactureEnteteStep)
                .next(loadFactureLigneStep)
                .next(loadFacturePaiementStep)
                .build();
    }
```

contains four steps, the problem is on my last three steps.Normally each step have a listener reader writer and its chunk oriented like this

```
@Bean("loadFactureEnteteStep")
    public Step loadFactureEnteteStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            @Qualifier("factureResource") Resource resource,
            @Qualifier("factureWriter") FactureItemWriter factureWriter,
            @Qualifier("listenerEntete") FetchFileToImportListener listenerEntete) throws IOException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("loadFactureEnteteStep")
                .<SapGenericElement, SapGenericElement> chunk(10000)
                .reader(factureEnteteReader(resource))
                .writer(factureWriter)
                .listener(listenerEntete)
                .build();
    }
```

for example this step needs to read a file from minio (3X XXX lines ) and insert it to my database meanwhile writing a report for each record in another file on minio ( to this point all good ).

Lately, when i m executing this job i get an error

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [Amazon s3 resource [bucket='bucket-app4155-8252-front-caisse-distrib' and object='xfb/in/dsie1021-sfr_distribution_loos/52941/FichierSepares_5686/LST_ENTETES_5686.csv']]

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I tried to decrease my chunk size to 5000/500/100 but after certain time during the processing i get the same error.

I did also set the timeouts for my amazonS3 client :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("public")
private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

private void configureS3ClientTimeouts() {
        if (amazonS3 != null) {
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ((AmazonS3Client) amazonS3).getClientConfiguration();
            if (clientConfiguration != null) {
                clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(5);
                clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(7200000);  // 2 hours
                clientConfiguration.withTcpKeepAlive(true);
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("ClientConfiguration is null!! S3 TIMEOUT NOT SET!!");
            }
        }
}
```

tried to add the @Retryable annotation

```
@Retryable(value = { SocketException.class, Exception.class },
               maxAttempts = 3,
               backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2))
```

but nothing seems to work really for my case !